# How to handle illegal characters in XML attributes "NAME" value

Tags: xml

Say I have a piece of XML that looks like the following:

```
<row Johnson&amp;Johnson="good" M&amp;Ms ="bad" /> --self closing tag
```

or

```
<row Johnson&amp;Johnson="good" M&amp;Ms ="bad" </row>
```

I have escaped the & character in the attribute name value but it seems like it is still illegal. Can you have attribute NAME values with escaped illegal characters? If so how?

Comment: That isn't a piece of XML. So you can't use any technology that's designed to process XML; you'll need to use raw text processing to turn this stuff into XML before you can do anything useful with it. Rather than repairing the data, however, it's more important to repair the process that generates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[&](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26/index.htm), 0x26,  isn't allowed in XML names:

[Section 2.3, "Common Syntactic constructs"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar)

```
[4]NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
[4a]NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't have an ampersand in a name of any kind. As a result, you don't have XML at all. You've just got some text that does not amount to well-formed XML.

Consider using something more like the following as an alternative:

```
<products>
    <product name="Johnson&amp;Johnson" quality="good"/>
    <product name="M&amp;Ms" quality="bad" />
</products>
```

Comment: You have not answer my question? Can you or can you not have attribute names with illegal characters? All you did was rearrange my xml example if I take out eh &amp; it would be totally valid so what's your point

Comment: @Mike: sorry, thought I was clear. No, you can't have ampersands in a name of any kind. The XML I posted was an example of a legal way to store the same data.